# JS Script link accepting PHP variables and showing %27

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a `<script>` link were I pass vaiables into it however on the network tab in the console its showing `%27` why?

**Code:**

`type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount='".<?php echo $price;?>.`

**Full Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<?php if($product->is_on_sale())
        {
            $price = $product->get_sale_price();
            echo 'sale';
        }else{
            $price = $product->get_price();
            echo 'Normal';
    }

echo 'The Price is:'. $price;
?>
<script async src="widget-0.1.0.js?type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount=".<?php echo $price;?>" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: your url contains `'` in `amount='"` so `'` this'll encoded to `%27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Satpal says, encoded value of `'` is `%27`

remove the single quote like:

```
type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount=".<?php echo $price;?>
```

as it is also useless in your query string so you can remove it, and try again.

Edited: Instead of:

```
type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount=".<?php echo $price;?>"
```

try

```
type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount=<?php echo $price; ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks,  I uploaded the full code - My echo with the price is giving me $75 but the url is blank why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this .remove space if it is present .

```
<?php
$price = 27;
?>
<script src="http://testSite.com/resources/js/animatedcollapse.js?type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount=<?php echo $price;?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned the single quotes in code block.But there is not single quotes in script attributes.And also you need to remove dot and try like this:

```
<script async src="widget-0.1.0.js?type=calculator&min=50&max=400&amount="<?=$price?>" type="application/javascript"></script>
```